# NSFileCoordinator leak

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, nsfilecoordinator

This is one trivial question of memory management related with blocks and I am not sure when/where `fc` should be released

```
NSFileCoordinator *fc = [[NSFileCoordinator alloc] initWithFilePresenter:nil];
NSError *error = nil;
[fc coordinateWritingItemAtURL:sourceURL
                       options:NSFileCoordinatorWritingForDeleting
                         error:&error
                    byAccessor:^(NSURL *newURL) {

            // if error is not nil this block will not be called
            NSError *anError = nil;
            NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
            [fm removeItemAtURL:newURL error:&anError];
            dispatch_async(q_main, ^{
                // change to the main queue and update the UI
                completion(anError);
        });
        // *** (1) Release here ? ***
        // [fc release];
        }];

// *** (2) or Release here ? ***
// [fc release]

if (error) {
    // change to the main queue and update the UI
    dispatch_async(q_main, ^{
        completion(error);
    });
}
```

I think releasing at (1) would be OK (no leaks) but is this really the standard way of doing things? (releasing an object in the block that the same object calls??). I feel some weirdness here.

At (2), Is also OK but only because the accessor block is called synchronously.

For learning purposes... what if that the accessor block would be called *asynchronously*? (An imaginary case not necessary of NSFileCoordinator) In such a case would I need to make `fc` an ivar or is it just fine to do as the first approach?

Any help is appreciated

:)

Comment: This is an anti-answer, but since you're using 10.7 why not use ARC?

Comment: I thought so too, but I simply don't like the idea of moving to ARC without knowing these details :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the given code, I would release at (2).  If you release at (1) you could tear down `fc` from underneath itself. There is no way to know what `fc` might need do after invoking the block.

For the asynchronous case, I've used code like this (although not with `NSFileCoordinator`):

```
__block NSWindowController *wc = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"foo"];
[NSApp beginSheet:[wc window] modalForWindow:[self window] completionHandler:^(NSInteger returnCode) {
    if(NSOKButton == returnCode) {
      // Do something
    }
    [wc release], wc = nil;
  }];
```

`-beginSheet:modalForWindow:completionHandler:` is a category I've added to `NSApplication`.

Comment: I think (2) is the best place :) . Also you said that you wouldn't release it at (1) because we don't know what `fc` is doing after the block, but in the supposed case we would and it would be the very last thing it does, would it be OK to release it there?

Comment: Yes, I think if you knew that the very last thing done by `fc` is to invoke your block, then releasing at (1) or (2) would be equivalent

Comment: I think under ARC an implicit `retain` is generated within the block so anything it needs is available even if the caller is long gone and released everything. I suppose without ARC maybe doing the same thing would be good and have your release both places but add another retain somewhere? Does this make any sense?